# Firefox automatically moves when title/header is out of screen

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

Recently, I've noticed that when I move firefox so that the title bar is out of the screen, it automatically moves back in.

[Before window auto-move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUS1x.png)

[After window auto-move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzW9Z.png)

This is very annoying as I'm used to watching videos without the title and headers taking screen space.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: It's not FF but the desktop environment who does that. But why on earth would  you do that? Why don't just use the "picture-in-picture" feature?

Comment: Shortcuts (e.g. fast-forward) don't work for picture-in-picture. This window auto-movement doesn't happen on chrome or any other programs.